# Disable Folder Options in Windows XP, Vista or 7

Tags: windows

As an administrator, can I disable the folder options in the control panel for other accounts than mine? What's the possible way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a Group Policy called "Removes* the Folder Options menu item from the Tools menu". It's under User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Explorer.

* not my typo. That's what I see under XP. (you'd expect "remove" not "removes")

Comment: Thank you. This will disable the 'folder options' for the user which is logged in  (that is the administrator) and it is not a universal setting. All the other accounts will still be able to access 'folder options'. I want just opposite of it. What I want is full access for me and no access for other accounts.

Also, Currently I have Windows 7 installed as main OS. Can you please tell me of any option for Windows 7?